# How can I get array from GET request?

Tags: php, arrays, yii, get

I have a trouble:
I have url of view:

> ?materials=1&materials=2&materials=3&materials=4&materials=5&materials=6

How can I get it in **array** throw Yii mechanism?

```
Yii::app()->request->getParam('materials')
```

Not working

```
$_GET['materials']
```

Too not working

Url is static and can not change

This URL was created https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl plugin

Comment: You will need to change the url to `?materials[]=1&materials[]=2...`

Comment: Unfortunately https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl plugin does not support those notation

Answer (score 1):

PHP automatically parses parameter as an array, if it ends by `[]`. (i.e. `?materials[]=1&materials[]=2&materials[]=3&materials[]=4&materials[]=5&materials[]=6`) Otherwise you can parse query string manually to solve your issue. Look at [this](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php#76792)